# Calendar for Android 2.2

Tags: android, calendar

I want  to retrieve events from my  google calendar on my phone. Is there any good samples out there? I am new to the Calendar and need a little help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is involved with ContentProviders. Specificaly you're looking for the code found for the ContentProvider for the Calendar.

This may help you get started:

[Calendar Source Code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar)

[Calendar ContentProvider](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_calendarprovider)

Comment: It should be following the same style.. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Those links, no offense to JoxTraex, are overly robust if all you are trying to do is get access to the local calendar database/URI.

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/instance/when").buildUpon();
long currentTime = new Date().getTime();    //Get current time

ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
ContentUris.appendId(builder, currentTime + DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);

Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(), new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + calID, null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

Now all you have to do is parse your cursor and you will have the events for the week prior to today and the upcoming week.

You can of course change the information in the ContentUris.appendId(...) to anything you like and get interesting results. For an app I am working on I am letting the user set a variable that will dictate how far back/forward to return events for.

Once there are tons of 4.0+ devices out there, then all this will be much more simple.